# Change Default Date Time format to specific "dd/mm/yyyy" format in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click of bootstrap3 datepicker I am getting selected date and setting it as innerHTML to a table .

Below is my code

```
$('[id^="dp"]').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
        // `e` here contains the extra attributes
        var Date = e.date;
        newDate=Date.(How to change format here ) 
        $(this).text(newDate);
 });
```

Currently e.Date giving me date in format

> Tue Sep 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

As per my knowledge its default format in jQuery .

How to change it in dd/mm/yyyy ??

Comment: Which datepicker plugin are you using? Why can't you just use `var date = $(this).val()`?

Comment: Are you trying to catch selected date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format?

Comment: @BenM I am using bootstrap3 datepicker

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay , I am trying to design editable row in html table , on click of table cell it will be editable and update new date by selecting new date from datepicker

Comment: @Jack, I am asking specifically about `changeDate`. What do you want to achieve on that event? I am asking because datepicker gives many options which you can use. So probably I can suggest you something.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay , its ok Himanshu , other people got the problem . Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You All ready getting everything in e.date

Seprate the month , day and year and than append them to get your desired format

```
var date = new Date(e.date),
    yr = date.getFullYear(),
    month = date.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth(),
    day = date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate(),
    newDate = day + '/' + month + '/' + yr;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toLocaleDateString()` to achieve this:

```
var test = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString();
alert(test);
```